# Compute moment and quantiles of a stream of data

Tags: estimation, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing

I'd like to compute the moments and quantiles of a random variable which is the output of a sensor.

I don't intend to store all the values this sensor outputs (let's say it outputs one value each 15 minutes), but rather keep batches of these values (for example a two weeks' batch) that I'll discard from time to time.

I was considering estimating the probability density function of a batch of outputs with scikit's KernelDensity. I then discard the batch and when I get hold of a new batch of values I update the estimate of the probability density with these new values.

I know that the probability density function that I estimate for each batch separately converges almost surely to the real density but I don't know if this result still holds if I compute the density incrementally as defined in the above paragraph.

Is it the way I should do ?

Comment: One batch would be less than $10^5$ values.  A year's worth (25 batches) would still be only a few million values, requiring perhaps 10 MB uncompressed storage. Is there some kind of restriction on your storage or computing systems that precludes storing this many numbers at once?  For systems with such restrictions, there is no problem updating the moments: the challenge lies in updating the quantiles. Both problems have been addressed in threads here.  Try [searching for "online"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=online%20quantile).

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that I need to process the output of ten thousands of sensors. Thanks for the threads you hinted at, I didn't know what was the English term for this specific problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a start, I wanted to refer you to a journal article called [A Fast Algorithm for Approximate Quantiles in High Speed Data Streams](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1271880). This is a paper that I have referenced myself before and used in practice when building software that analyze stream data. Additionally, this method was also discussed and implemented [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/497936) on Intel's site.

Below is a snapshot of the simplest code snippet used to compute snapshots of quantiles for streaming data taken from the Intel site showing how the algorithm was implemented.

```
#include "mkl_vsl.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 3      /* dimension of the task */
#define N   1000   /* number of observations */
#define M   100    /* number of quantiles to compute */
#define EPS 0.01   /* accuracy of quantile computation */

int main()
{
   int i, status;
   VSLSSTaskPtr task;
   float x[DIM][N];  /* matrix of observations */
   float q_order[M], quants[M];
   float params;
   MKL_INT q_order_n;
   MKL_INT p, n, nparams, xstorage;
   int indices[DIM]={1,0,0}; /* the first vector component is processed */

   /* Parameters of the task and initialization */
   p = DIM;
   n = N;

   q_order_n = M;
   xstorage  = VSL_SS_MATRIX_STORAGE_ROWS;
   params    = EPS;
   nparams   = VSL_SS_SQUANTS_ZW_PARAMS_N;

   /* Calculate percentiles */
   for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ ) q_order[i] = (float)i / (float)M;

   /* Create a task */
   status = vslsSSNewTask( &task, &p, &n, &xstorage, x, 0, indices );

   /* Initialize the task parameters */
   status = vslsSSEditStreamQuantiles( task, &q_order_n, q_order,
                                       quants, &nparams, &params );

   /* Compute the percentiles with accuracy eps */
   status = vslsSSCompute( task, VSL_SS_STREAM_QUANTS,
                                 VSL_SS_METHOD_SQUANTS_ZW );

   /* Deallocate the task resources */
   status = vslSSDeleteTask( &task );

   return 0;
}
```

As Zhang notes in his paper, "Streaming quantile computation has several constraints. Data streams are transient and can arrive at a high speed. Furthermore, the stream size may not be known apriori. Streaming computations therefore require single pass algorithms with small space requirement and which are able to handle arbitrary sized streams. In order to guarantee the precision of the result, the algorithm should ensure random or deterministic error bound for the quantile computation."

I would start by reading the paper and then going from there. Here is a [link](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~zhangq/PUBLICATIONS/SSDBM07-Qi%20Zhang-FastQStream.pdf) to the PDF of the paper. Multiple methods are discussed before their fast algorithm is introduced.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But you haven't given your opinion of the method I originally planned to use (that is estimating the density function)

Comment: I don't have a problem with going the density estimation route. My only concern is speed. A place to start might be this journal article: http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~wli/publications/deosd.pdf. I might be inclined to do a small scale speed test here to evaluate the performance differences.

Comment: Ok so there is no concern on the convergence of the resulting density function when I simulate previous deleted values with the estimated density to which I add the new batch of values in order to compute a new estimate of the density. I should say that I'm a little concerned by this step. Speed is not my concern since the sensor issues values quite slowly.

Answer (score 1):

I have no background regarding your task. However that reminded me of an idea I have to adapt a classifier (non-Bayesian, but static classifier) to the changes in time (specifically I was trying to adapt a random forest).

So, my idea is to collect a sample for a period of time: in your case 2 weeks if you can afford that. Than for each new hour (could be any other period of time), add to the sample the new data points, and remove data points from the oldest hour.

It might have some problems, because it depends a lot on how do you choose those periods. Larger periods means smaller effects for the new input. Smaller periods could mean that new data could perturb the old distribution too much. It depends on what do you really need for.

[Later edit] After few google searches I have found that this is an old procedure known as "sliding window", and there are a lot of papers for "sliding window quantiles".